# "JSONValue" Keyword not getting recognised while using SBJson ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, sbjson

i have copied `SBJson` folder into my project and also `#import "SBJson.h"`

But still i am not getting

```
NSDictionary *result = [strResult JSONValue];
```

Even Xcode does not show any option `JSONValue`;

even if i write `JSONValue` than it prompt me error

```
No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'JSONValue'
```

Comment: for that i need json framework

Comment: i just copied json folder and it prompt me arc is unavailable.

Comment: http://www.codeography.com/2011/10/10/making-arc-and-non-arc-play-nice.html

Comment: Look at your first answer below.  Use it.

Comment: NSJSONSerialization is easy to use, look at answer below.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need `SBJson` for this.

There is a native class `NSJSONSerialization` that does this much faster and without the need to import anything.

```
NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[strResult dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
```

A better way would just be to use the `NSData` straight from he request...

```
NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:theJSONDataFromTheRequest options:0 error:nil];
```

Comment: This is how we should be parsing JSON now.  SBJson was created for the times before we had built in JSON serialization.

Comment: `NSString *response = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.....php"];
    const char *convert = [response UTF8String];
    NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:convert];
    NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
    NSArray *ads = [responseString JSONValue];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[ads objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:1]);`

Why this code not working @fogmeister

Comment: @gokcokkececi what are you trying to do? The string you have is just text not JSON. You are not getting anything from the web here.

Comment: strResult is what ? is it NSData or NSString  or NSURL or NSDIctionary

Comment: @Fogmeister please suggest

Comment: @UnicoRahul `strResult` is taken from the OP's question and is an NSString in my case. I have edited the answer to show how you can just use the NSData though.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use SBJson the replace #import **"SBJSON.h"** with #import **"JSON.h"** and you will get it working.

Comment: As the author of SBJson I don't understand why you would say that. This would mean that you're using a release that is over 3 years old, rather than use a recent release. Anyway, unless you need to support iOS4 or lower you should just use Apple's `NSJSONSerialisation`.