# how to parse this json data in ios7

Tags: ios, json, ios7, nsjsonserialization

The code:

```
NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"alamghareeb.com/mobileData.ashx?catid=0&No=10"]; 
NSData * data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; 
NSError * error; 
NSMutableDictionary * json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
NSMutableArray * referanceArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray * periodArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 
NSArray * responseArr = [NSArray arrayWithArray:json[@"item"]];

for (NSDictionary * dict in responseArr) { 
    [referanceArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"created"]]; 
}
```

The JSON looks like:

```
{ 
  "item" = [ 


  {
  "id" : "2292",

  "created" : "10/01/2015 10:21:18 ص",

  "title" : "الإمارات: ملابس رياضية فاخرة لتحسين أداء الإبل في السباقات ", 

  "image_url" : "http://alamghareeb.com/Photos/L63556482078696289044.jpg",

  "image_caption" : ""

   },

  {

  "id" : "2291",

  "created" : "10/01/2015 09:28:11 ص",

  "title" : "طبيبة تجميل 'مزورة' تحقن مرضاها بالغراء والاسمنت",

  "image_url" : "http://alamghareeb.com/Photos/L63556478891290039015.jpg",

  "image_caption" : ""
  } 
 ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for posting on the json but can you tell us what you have done to parse this your self?

Comment: I would recommend that you use a JSON parser.

Comment: NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://alamghareeb.com/mobileData.ashx?catid=0&No=10"];  
    NSData * data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError * error;
    NSMutableDictionary  * json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
     NSMutableArray * referanceArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray * periodArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSArray * responseArr = [NSArray arrayWithArray:json[@"item"]];

Comment: for(NSDictionary * dict in responseArr)
    {   [referanceArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"created"]];
       }
@MZaragoza

Comment: @sojoudahmad You need to put that code in your question, and not as comments here

Comment: By the way, you generally shouldn't use mutable objects unless you really need mutable objects. For example, I'd change the declaration of the `json` object as follows: `NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error: &error];`

Comment: Also, it's inadvisable to use `dataWithContentsOfURL` (a synchronous JSON function). I'd use `sendAsynchronousRequest` or other asynchronous method.

Comment: Hint:  There is an `error:` parm on `JSONObjectWithData:`.  Use it.

Comment: And first of all: use properly formatted JSON to start with... the response you are getting from alamghareeb.com is faulty.

Answer (score 3):

This JSON is not valid. Did you build it manually? The `"item" = ...` should be `"item" : ...`.

In the future, you can run your JSON through http://jsonlint.com to verify any issues. Likewise, you should add error checking in your Objective-C code, e.g.

```
NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
if (!json) {
    NSLog(@"JSON parsing error: %@", error);
}
```

I'd also suggest changing your server code to not build JSON manually, but take advantage of JSON functions (e.g. if PHP, build associative arrays and then generate JSON output using the `json_encode` function).

---

So, once you fix the JSON error, to parse the results might look like:

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
if (!dictionary) {
    NSLog(@"NSJSONSerialization error: %@", error);
    return;
}

NSArray *items = dictionary[@"item"];

for (NSDictionary *item in items) {
    NSString *identifier = item[@"id"];
    NSString *created    = item[@"created"];
    NSString *title      = item[@"title"];
    NSString *urlString  = item[@"image_url"];
    NSString *caption    = item[@"image_caption"];

    NSLog(@"identifier = %@", identifier);
    NSLog(@"created = %@", created);
    NSLog(@"title = %@", title);
    NSLog(@"urlString = %@", urlString);
    NSLog(@"caption = %@", caption);
}
```

Comment: OP actually posted part of the endpoint result: http://alamghareeb.com/mobileData.ashx?catid=0&No=10 at least part of the problem seems to be on the server side

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSJSONSerialization`. No need to import any class.

```
NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[strResult dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
```

or use `NSData` directly as

```
NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:theJSONDataFromTheRequest options:0 error:nil];
```

Source : [Stackoveflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696800/jsonvalue-keyword-not-getting-recognised-while-using-sbjson)